# iphone app is working on simulator but not on device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios5, xcode4.3

my app is working fine on simulator but not on device...
I am able to see only first views of each tab as I used `UITabViewController` ..

After trying a lot when I replaced one of `UIViewController` by taking .xib i.e. by using interface builder,I am able to see change on my iPhone.
so,what will be the possible reasons  of it?
  Is there any way to solve this problem without have to replacing all viewcontrollers? because replacement will not be worthwhile....

Thanks a lot!

Comment: you should be able to get Log in the XCode console, what is says...

Comment: app works correct on simulator,so where to check log?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing this is a duplicate question, but check for capitalization. The simulator is not case sensitive, the devices are.

Comment: I dont understand your suggestion..capitalization for what?where I need to check?

Comment: if you use an image called "image.png" but call [UIImage imageNamed: "Image.png"] it will work on the simulator but not the device